# Can you export GIF of size 1600x1200 in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, animated-gif

I exported .mov file (800 MB, 1600x1200 px) from After Effects and imported in Photoshop. When tried to export it in 32/64/128/256, it gave me error

> Could not complete this operation. An unknown error has occurred

When I tried 800x600 and 1200x900 size GIF, it exported without any problem for all colors.

In the case of 1200x900, it failed once. But when I restarted Photoshop and tried again, it worked, I don't know why.
My PC has 8 GB RAM, Windows 10.

So can I export larger GIF files i.e., 1600x1200 px? Or is it not possible and hence I'm getting error?

Comment: Hi. Tech support questions are generally off-topic here on GDSE because they can't usually be solved without access to actual files or your computer system/set up. It would probably be more effective to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: does anybody know what the absolute maximum addressable size of a GIF is?

Comment: @BillyKerr Hello. I have seen many tech support questions already here. But couldn't find solution so posted a new one.

Comment: Use a video instead of an animated gif.

Comment: perhaps you could share what are you trying to accomplish instead. What is this GIF for? have you seen this? https://www.schoolofmotion.com/blog/gif-in-after-effects

Comment: I did the same. Exported lossless format though and imported in Ps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

I just exported a 2000*2000px GIF from my Photoshop without a problem using Save for Web and default settings. Here it is !

[image]

Comment: I guess it is related to hardware then. Although I can export it from Media Encoder, but problem is with Ps.

Comment: Judging my the `.mov`, OP is trying to export an animated gif, which may contain too much data for PS to handle (maybe a RAM issue? 8GB isn't much these days).